# How to see if a twilio message has been read?

Tags: next.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I have a nextjs project and I integrated twilio programmable chat. It basically works. Next step is to add notifications and I have very big problems due to the not updated or lack of doc. I tried [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/javascript/push-notifications-web) for web push notifications but I gave it up because after the step7 I don't know what to do and can't find anything about it.

What I want to do now is to get the status of the messages and eventually update them once I read them. First of all is it possible to do it? I don't find anything about twilio web notifications on the internet.

For example if I want to get the messages of a specific room I do as follows:

```
const response = await getTwilioClient(token, unique_room_name);
const messages = await response.channel.getMessages(MESSAGES_LIMIT);
```

`messages` has the following shape:

```
{
  hasNextPage: boolean,
  hasPrevPage: boolean,
  items: Message[],
  nextPage: () => Message[],
  prevPage: () => Message[],
}
```

And `Message` looks like this:

[image]

So how can I see the status of a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message read status is actually stored on the Member object. A Member is the object that represents a User in a Channel and it has a [`lastConsumedMessageIndex` property](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/6.0.0/docs/classes/Member.html#lastConsumedMessageIndex) which relates to the last message they read.

In order to read the `lastConsumedMessageIndex` property, you need to set where the member has read up to, using the Channel methods [`advanceLastConsumedMessageIndex`](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/6.0.0/docs/classes/Channel.html#advanceLastConsumedMessageIndex), [`setAllMessagesConsumed`](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/6.0.0/docs/classes/Channel.html#setAllMessagesConsumed) or [`setNoMessagesConsumed`](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/6.0.0/docs/classes/Channel.html#setNoMessagesConsumed).

I recommend you read the documentation on the [Message Consumption Horizon and Read Status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/consumption-horizon).

As an extra note, I see you're asking questions about Twilio Chat, however [Twilio Chat will be coming to the end of life in July 2022](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/programmable-chat-end-of-life). We recommend that you [migrate to the Twilio Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/migrating-chat-conversations) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @philnash. I am going to proceed with the migration and see what comes with this.